Unable to stop excel service after instancing it via com-object in Powershell
Can somebody explain to me why even after quitting excel via $excel.quit() and putting all the related variable to $null via $excel = $workbook = $worksheet = $null
And collecting garbage via [gc]::collect()
I’m unable to get the excel process to stop unless I use [System.GC]::GetTotalMemory($true) multiple time and only if I don’t use any of these to not get output: [void][System.GC]::GetTotalMemory($true), [System.GC]::GetTotalMemory($true)|out-null, $null = [System.GC]::GetTotalMemory($true)?
This happened no matter if I use [System.GC]::WaitForPendingFinalizers()
Interestingly if an error occurs and get thrown in the console the process can be stop even only with [gc]::collect(), but twice or trice
If the script get executed via cmd command powershell.exe -file “path to file” the process stop even after a single call to [gc]::collect().
I don’t send the script as it is very long but if it is necessary i can let you have the files via some hosting services.
I referred to this link:
Can't get all excel processes to stop when closing through Powershell
This one:
Under what circumstances, we need to call GC.Collect twice
And this one:
https://www.jhouseconsulting.com/jhouseconsulting/2017/09/25/addressing-the-powershell-garbage-collection-bug-1825
Thank you in advance
Franco

Have you tried the "Preferable alternative:" technique from the accepted answer to the first question you link to (https://stackoverflow.com/a/55423449/45375)? From what I can tell, it reliably works.

@mklement0 I consider you as a guru in Powershell, and I solved many problems thank to you. I thank you very much for all your work in this comunity. Yes I also tried isolate the script in a scope and call the garbage collection outside but the same strange things happen. It’s weeks that I rack my mind to understand why this happens

Actually the excel com object gets instantiated in a runspace and the quit() method, if the gui gets closed, occurs in the main scope, from which the runspace begin its invokation. The excel object returns in the main scope by a Synchronized HashTables

@mklement0 done and I also upvoted the reply. With regards to the current question if I will able to reproduce the issue in a simple script I will post it here
